# Pathfinding recursion runs out of memory in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I wrote this prolog program to find all possible paths in a grid:

```
travel([X,Y],[X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y+1.
travel([X,Y],[X,Y0]) :- Y0 is Y-1.
travel([X,Y],[X1,Y]) :- X1 is X+1.

move([X,Y],n,[X,Y1]) :- travel([X,Y],[X,Y1]).
move([X,Y],s,[X,Y0]) :- travel([X,Y],[X,Y0]).
move([X,Y],e,[X1,Y]) :- travel([X,Y],[X1,Y]).

safe([Xn,Yn],[Xg,Yg]) :-
  Xg >= Xn,
  Xn >= 0,
  Yg >= Yn,
  Yn >= 0. %next state should be whit-in grid

%% solve([X,Y],[TargetX,TargetY],[Xg,Yg],[FirstMove|OtherMoves])

solve([X,Y],[X,Y],_,[]).
solve([X,Y],[Xt,Yt],[Xg,Yg],[Fm|Om]) :-
  move([X,Y],Fm,[Xn,Yn]),
  safe([Xn,Yn],[Xg,Yg]),
  solve([Xn,Yn],[Xt,Yt],[Xg,Yg],Om).
```

For `solve`, [X,Y] is the current position. So my ending state is when the current position equals to target position. However, when I run it, I got out of memory error. Any idea what I did wrong? Any help is appreciated!

```
?- solve([1,2],[4,2],[3,4],P).
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 0.5Gb, global: 0.4Gb, trail: 29.0Mb
ERROR:   Stack depth: 951,746, last-call: 0%, Choice points: 1,903,475
ERROR:   Possible non-terminating recursion:
ERROR:     [951,746] user:solve([length:2], [length:2], [length:2], _114212638)
ERROR:     [951,745] user:solve([length:2], [length:2], [length:2], [length:1|_114212704])

?- length(P,4),solve([1,2],[4,2],[3,4],P).
false.

?- length(P,5),solve([1,2],[4,2],[3,4],P).
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is infinitely looping between north and south movements. Try removing the south clauses in `move` and `travel` and it will work.

To debug how this is happening try using `trace` and see a recursive calls to `solve` you can see what is going on.

```
   Exit: (15) move([1, 3], n, [1, 4]) ? 
   Call: (15) safe([1, 4], [4, 4]) ? s
   Exit: (15) safe([1, 4], [4, 4]) ? 
   Call: (15) solve([1, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4], _3490) ? 
   Call: (16) move([1, 4], _3804, [_3822, _3828]) ? s
   Exit: (16) move([1, 4], n, [1, 5]) ? 
   Call: (16) safe([1, 5], [4, 4]) ? s
   Fail: (16) safe([1, 5], [4, 4]) ? 
   Redo: (16) move([1, 4], _3804, [_3822, _3828]) ? s
   Exit: (16) move([1, 4], s, [1, 3]) ? 
   Call: (16) safe([1, 3], [4, 4]) ? s
   Exit: (16) safe([1, 3], [4, 4]) ? 
   Call: (16) solve([1, 3], [3, 4], [4, 4], _3806) ? 
   Call: (17) move([1, 3], _4326, [_4344, _4350]) ? s
   Exit: (17) move([1, 3], n, [1, 4]) ? 
   Call: (17) safe([1, 4], [4, 4]) ? s
   Exit: (17) safe([1, 4], [4, 4]) ? 
   Call: (17) solve([1, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4], _4328) ? 
   Call: (18) move([1, 4], _4642, [_4660, _4666]) ? s
   Exit: (18) move([1, 4], n, [1, 5]) ? 
   Call: (18) safe([1, 5], [4, 4]) ? s
   Fail: (18) safe([1, 5], [4, 4]) ?
```

Also you seem to be pattern matching variable names in `move :- travel`, which will also not work. `move(P1, n, P2)` will try north and south clauses not just the first one(try `move([2, 2], s, X)` and see that the first solution is north movement). This will work but with south clause you will have infinite recursion.

```
move([X,Y], n, [X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y+1.
move([X,Y], s, [X,Y1]) :- Y1 is Y-1.
move([X,Y], e, [X1,Y]) :- X1 is X+1.
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I saw what was going on by using the trace command. Now I have to find a "default" way to execute a function if there are no other options. Any idea to implement this?
I tried using length(P,2),solve([1,1],[2,2],[2,2],P). on a 2x2 grid which is quite easy because I know there are two results with only two steps. But on a bigger grid it becomes quite difficult.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by 'default execute when there are no other options'. Do want to do something else when `solve` fails?

Comment: If you simply want to stop after finding a single solution use `once/1` or cut. But if you want a more solutions then you need a more general predicate to disqualify certain move sequences. Eg. a streak of `n`'s cannot be followed by a `s` etc... If you want to have more fun with this try to pick a `random_member(D, [n, s, e])` and try that move direction.

Comment: All worked out! I introduced another list to track where I was so I can exclude the duplicates. Thanks again!

Comment: @JohnZ : Does excluding duplicates mean your path cannot criss-cross? If so then you will still be missing some un-optimal solutions (may be not since you are not going west).